# Как сделать, чтобы не убирался активный класс?

Tags: javascript

```
const servicesList = document.querySelector('.services__сategory');
const activeClass = "active-category";

servicesList.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
const element = event.target.closest(".category-item");
if (!element) return;

const activeElement = element.parentElement.querySelector(".active-category");
activeElement && activeElement.classList.remove(activeClass);
(element === activeElement) || element.classList.add(activeClass);
});
```

Как сделать, чтобы при клике на уже активный элемент класс .active-category не убирался?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В данном случае лишним является условие:

```
(element === activeElement)
```

Если оно истинно, выражение после `||` не выполняется, следовательно и класс не добавляется заново.

Для решения достаточно его просто убрать.

Так же стоит использовать `if` для выбора действия, чтобы не путаться в последствии.

В итоге код может выглядеть так:

```
const servicesList = document.querySelector('.services__сategory');
const activeClass = "active-category";

servicesList.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
    const element = event.target.closest(".category-item");
    if (!element) return;

    const activeElement = element.parentElement.querySelector(".active-category");
    activeElement?.classList?.remove(activeClass);

    element.classList.add(activeClass);
});
```

Comment: Благодарю покорно

Answer (score 0):

Конечно это работает но думаю как-то так

```
const servicesList = document.querySelector('.services__сategory');
const activeClass = "active-category";

servicesList.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
const element = event.target.closest(".category-item");
if (!element) return;

const activeElement = element.parentElement.querySelector(".active-category");
//activeElement && activeElement.classList.remove(activeClass);
(element === activeElement) || element.classList.add(activeClass);
});
```

Единственно у вас назначается `element.classList.add(activeClass)` как там по логике разбирайтесь сами